# Error on reconnect with SocketAsyncEventArgs : Only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous

When I tried to reestablish a connection to my Socket I get the following error :

**Error** : Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
**SocketErrorCode** : System.Net.Sockets.SocketError.AddressAlreadyInUse

Each time I want to reconnect, I first call the Disconnect() method. But even if my socket is disconnected I have an error when I tried to reconnect with the Connect() method.

```
    public SocketError Connect()
    {
        //Open socket connection
        SocketAsyncEventArgs connectArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();

        connectArgs.UserToken = _socket;
        connectArgs.RemoteEndPoint = _hostEndPoint;
        connectArgs.Completed += OnConnect;

        _socket.ConnectAsync(connectArgs); //ERROR : Only one usage of each socket address...

        _autoConnectEvent.WaitOne();

        if (connectArgs.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
        {
            throw new SocketException((Int32)connectArgs.SocketError);
        }

        return connectArgs.SocketError;
    }


    public void Disconnect()
    {
        _socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        _socket.Disconnect(true);
    }
```

Does anyone know how to avoid this error?

Comment: Are you testing both ends of the connection on the same machine using the same socket number? This has bitten me in the past.

Comment: Yes, same machine, same socket number. Should I do something with the ReuseAddress Property?

Comment: Did you tried with a different socket number for each end?

Comment: I cannot change the address and port number. Thats the only way to connect to the server

Comment: I believe that's going to be your problem: you can only have one app using any given socket on a machine. Here's a good blog entry on the subject and possible workarounds: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dgorti/archive/2005/09/18/470766.aspx

Comment: Why can I reconnect when I close my application? I should get the same error no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation here : [Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dgorti/archive/2005/09/18/470766.aspx)

Thanks @competent_tech